# Angular 11: Cannot Connect to SQL Server from API Controller -- GET Method

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, angular, visual-studio, get

As a precursor, I am using SQL Server Management Studio 18 for my Database and I am writing in Angular 11.

I am trying to write a GET method to pull my table `dbo.Information` from my database `WeatherTemplate` in SQL Server Management Studio 18. I'm continuing to recieve this error though and I am unable to resolve it:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)'

Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

With what I have written so far I should be able to use Postman and run my GET method to retrieve the table. My first assumption is I made a syntax error somewhere but I can't seem to find anything out of order. My code is below...

**Controller Get Method**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Get()
        {

            String query = @"select WeatherID, Date, TemperatureC, TemperatureF, Summary from dbo.Information";

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("WeatherAppCon");
            SqlDataReader myReader;
            using(SqlConnection myCon=new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
            {
                myCon.Open();
                using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myCon))
                {
                    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    table.Load(myReader); ;

                    myReader.Close();
                    myCon.Close();
                }
            }

            return new JsonResult(table);    
        }
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "WeatherAppCon": "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=WeatherTemplate; Integrated Security=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

namespace PROBLEM
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //Enable CORS
            services.AddCors(c =>
            {
                c.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });

            //JSON Serializer
            services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore)
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
                
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
               
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                  
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your database is not "in SQL Server Management Studio". SSMS is just a client for connecting to and managing databases. It doesn't host databases itself. You've provided us a whole lot of code here, but none of it's really helpful. If your connection string isn't correct, or your database isn't set up to listen at the proper location, then none of that other code is going to matter.

Comment: What values do you supply in SSMS to connect to your sql server instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error will happen due to wrong connection string

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "WeatherAppCon": "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=WeatherTemplate; Integrated Security=true"
  }
```

It should be in below format

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
     "WeatherAppCon": "Server=<your server name>;Database=<your database name>;User Id=<your userId>;Password=<your password>;"
}
```

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.